# What is the black backdrop in outdoor shots for?

Tags: outdoor, backdrops, fashion

I have seen this in many famous fashion shoots done outside.
Something like this picture below:

[image]

So does the model stand in front of it as backdrop?  then wouldn't it block the background view in outdoors?  How do they use it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of several ways you *could* use it...

- **backdrop:** If the creative directory wants two looks with the same model in the same clothes, shooting both at the same time could save some time. Just because you're on a beach doesn't mean that *every* shot has to include the beach.
- **lighting modifier:** Shooting with the screen out of view but close to the model could add some direction to the light. In the shot you posted, the sky is overcast and the light would be coming from all directions; blocking the light on one side would give the shot some dimension.
- **privacy screen:** Two or three of those screens arranged together could give the models a bit of hidden space for changing.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought about it this way, ( For Light Modifier in a overcast day to give some direction to the light ).
Silly question: What if it is a windy day? What do they do?

Comment: I'd guess they deal with it. Find a different location, get three assistants to hold the screen up, wait an hour and hope the wind dies down, call it a day and try again tomorrow, bust out more speedlights and dial down the ambient exposure a couple notches...